# Was ist die Bedeutung von "dabei" in diesem Kontext?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

Als ich einige Regeln über Nominalisierung las, fand ich folgende Beispiele:

**Verbalstil**

> Es ist ein Bestandteil des Lernprozesses, wenn sie dabei von den Normen der Muttersprache abweichen.

**Nominalstil**

> Abweichungen von den Normen der Muttersprache sind dabei ein Bestandteil des Lernprozesses.

Ich weiß nicht, was die genaue Bedeutung von *dabei* in beiden Sätzen ist.

Auf Englisch hat *dabei* folgende Übersetzungen:

1. thereby
2. in doing so
3. at the same time

Ich glaube, dass die passende Bedeutung *thereby* ist?
Habe ich recht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dabei` verweist hier auf einen Vorgang, der offenbar zuvor beschrieben wurde. *Bei* diesem Vorgang kommt es zu *Abweichungen von den Normen der Muttersprache*, und die beiden Sätze erläutern, dass diese Abweichungen als Teil eines Lernprozesses zu verstehen sind, der Teil des geschilderten Vorgangs ist.

[Das Adverb dabei](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dabei#Bedeutung3) wird hier also in der Bedeutung "im Verlaufe von" gebraucht.

Ich glaube eher nicht, daß eine der drei englischen Übersetzungen hier brauchbar ist; jedenfalls würde ich das nicht ohne Kenntnis des Kontextes beurteilen wollen. Aber letztlich geht es hier ja um die deutsche Sprache, nicht um die englische.

Comment: Yep. "Dabei" stands for "bei diesem" (which would not be idiomatic), so the question reduces to understanding the preposition "bei", which is probably hard enough.

Answer (score 5):

*Dabei* bezieht sich in fast allen Fällen auf die Handlung im vorherigen Satz oder Satzteil. In diesem Beispiel gehe ich von *dabei* im Sinne von *währenddessen*, *während des Lernprozesses* aus. Somit wäre *in doing so* auf jeden Fall richtig.

*Thereby* würde man eher mit *dadurch* übersetzen, dies wäre richtig, wenn der Satz eine Folgerung aus dem vorherigen wäre, was hier jedoch keinen Sinn macht.

Comment: In diesem Satz ist es sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass sich dabei auf den Lernprozess bezieht, da der zweite Teilsatz schon als Teil der Tätigkeit des im ersten Teil genannten Vorgangs etabliert wird. "dabei" hätte dann sozusagen "nichts zu tun". Das noch bessere Argument ist aber, dass der Satz im Nominalstil immer noch ein "dabei" enthält. Bezöge sich das auch "Lernprozess" wäre es "... beim Lernprozess Bestandteil des Lernprozesses."